# Javascript to change CSS left value from px to % based on browser size

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a div

```
#footer_container {
  position: fixed;
  width: 540px;
  height: 45px;
  margin-left: -270px
}
```

And I would like the CSS `left` value to be `left: 50%` for Browser-widths >1000px and `left: 500px` for browser widths of <1000px

I know this can easily be done with media queries but they are problematic and dont work with IE8.

Can someone please do this with javascript? Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
#footer_container {
    ...
    left: 500px;
}
@media all and (min-width: 1000px) {
    #footer_container {left: 50%;}
}
```

Works with CSS3-compatible browsers, updates automatically with no need for `window.onresize` or similar code... or indeed any code.

Comment: He asked for a non media query solution (fwiw). But since you went there I'll throw in that you can get media queries to work in IE8 with respond.js. https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond

Answer (score 2):

With jQuery:

```
if ($("body").width() > 1000){
    $("#footer_container").css("left","50%");
}
else{
    $("#footer_container").css("left","500px");
}
```

See Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/9ketB/

You can add a listener for window resize with [$("window").resize()](http://api.jquery.com/resize/)

Answer (score 1):

```
var left = ($(document).width() > 1000) ? "50%" : "500px"
$("#footer_container").css("left", left)
```